# Issue with cron utility

Tags: linux, path, cron

I am facing a weird issue with cron utility.
I have some script which if i run from shell works fine.
However, if run the same script using cron it results in error.

The error it says, is that it is not able to find a particular cmd.
I source my user shell file in the script that i am running.

Any possible reasons for this issue ?

Comment: Try to check the guide "debugging crontab" in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info . It is difficult to say without the code, but probably using the full path of the command would solve it.

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) might be better suited for this question and thus yield more/better answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a PATH issue. echo $PATH in terminal, then take the result and put it on the top of the cron file like PATH=/RESULT/STUFF